# ExtJS Grid not loading data from Ext.data.XmlStore

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, xmlstore

I have a grid that I'm trying to populate from an XmlStore, which is populated from an Xml String.  So far, the store appears to be load the XML just fine, but I cannot get the grid to load the store. (i.e. grid.getStore().getCount() is always 0.

```
// create the Data Stores for use by the grid
Ext.define('InterfaceModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', mapping: 'id' },
        { name: 'InterfaceName', mapping: 'InterfaceName' },
        { name: 'TX_OCTETS', mapping: 'TX_OCTETS' },
        { name: 'TX_BAD_OCTETS', mapping: 'TX_BAD_OCTETS' },
        { name: 'TX_FRM', mapping: 'TX_FRM' },
        { name: 'TX_BAD_FRM', mapping: 'TX_BAD_FRM' },
        { name: 'TX_MCAST', mapping: 'TX_MCAST' },
        { name: 'TX_BCAST', mapping: 'TX_BCAST' },
        { name: 'TX_PAUSE', mapping: 'TX_PAUSE' }
    ],
    idProperty: 'id'
});
```

My XML is as follows:

```
var gridData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Interfaces> <Interface> <id>1</id> <InterfaceName>GMAC1</InterfaceName> <TX_OCTETS>123234</TX_OCTETS> <TX_BAD_OCTETS>234</TX_BAD_OCTETS> <TX_FRM>234234</TX_FRM> <TX_BAD_FRM>2341</TX_BAD_FRM> <TX_MCAST>23</TX_MCAST> <TX_BCAST>56</TX_BCAST> <TX_PAUSE>8</TX_PAUSE></Interface> <Interface> <id>2</id> <InterfaceName>GMAC2</InterfaceName> <TX_OCTETS>123234</TX_OCTETS> <TX_BAD_OCTETS>234</TX_BAD_OCTETS> <TX_FRM>234234</TX_FRM> <TX_BAD_FRM>2341</TX_BAD_FRM> <TX_MCAST>23</TX_MCAST> <TX_BCAST>56</TX_BCAST> <TX_PAUSE>8</TX_PAUSE></Interface></Interfaces>';

var gridDataXml = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(gridData,'text/xml');

console.log ('xml', gridDataXml);  // everything looks fine
```

I then define my store using a memory proxy XML reader:

```
var eioaGridStore = new Ext.data.XmlStore({
    model: 'InterfaceModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            root: 'Interfaces',
            record: 'Interface',
            idProperty: 'id'
        }
    }
});
```

And then load the parsed XML DOM into the store:

```
eioaGridStore.loadRawData(gridDataXml);
```

If I getCount() on the store, it properly responds with 2.

Viewing the store from the Web Inspector shows 2 arrays (that I want to be rows in my grid) (pardon the formatting)

```
store 
Object
data: Object
allowFunctions: false
events: Object
generation: 3
getKey: function (record) {
hasListeners: Object
items: Array[2]
0: Object
data: Object
dirty: false
events: Object
hasListeners: Object
id: "InterfaceModel-1"
internalId: "1"
modified: Object
phantom: false
raw: Element
store: Object
stores: Array[1]
__proto__: Object
1: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
keys: Array[2]
length: 2
map: Object
sorters: Object
__proto__: Object
events: Object
eventsSuspended: 0
filters: Object
groupers: Object
hasListeners: Object
model: function i() {return this.constructor.apply(this,arguments)||null;}
modelDefaults: Object
pageSize: 25
proxy: Object
removed: Array[0]
sorters: Object
totalCount: 2
__proto__: Object
```

My grid component is as follows:

```
createGrid: function () {
    var me = this;

    return {
        id: 'eioaGrid',
        xtype: 'grid',
        border: true,
        store: this.eioaGridStore,
        columns: [{
            header: 'Interface',
            dataIndex: 'InterfaceName',
            align: 'center',
            sortable: true,
            tooltip: 'Axxia Interface'
        }, {
            text: 'OCTETS',
            sortable: false,
            width: 100,
            tooltip: 'Total number of octets in all frames.',
            columns: [{
                header: 'TX',
                width: 50,
                align: 'center',
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'TX_OCTETS',
                tooltip: 'Transmitted'
            }]
        }, {
            text: 'BAD OCTETS',
            sortable: false,
            width: 100,
            tooltip: 'Total number of octets in all bad frames.',
            columns: [{
                header: 'TX',
                width: 50,
                align: 'center',
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'TX_BAD_OCTETS',
                tooltip: 'Transmitted'
            }]
        }, {
            text: 'FRAMES',
            sortable: false,
            width: 100,
            tooltip: 'Total number of frames.',
            columns: [{
                header: 'TX',
                width: 50,
                align: 'center',
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'TX_FRM',
                tooltip: 'Transmitted'
            }]
        }, {
            text: 'BAD FRAMES',
            sortable: false,
            width: 100,
            tooltip: 'Total number of bad frames.',
            columns: [{
                header: 'TX',
                width: 50,
                align: 'center',
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'TX_BAD_FRM',
                tooltip: 'Transmitted'
            }]
        }, {
            text: 'MULTICAST',
            sortable: false,
            width: 100,
            tooltip: 'Multicast Frames: good non-pause frames with a multicast destination address which is not the broadcast address.',
            columns: [{
                header: 'TX',
                width: 50,
                align: 'center',
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'TX_MCAST',
                tooltip: 'Transmitted'
            }]
        }, {
            text: 'BROADCAST',
            sortable: false,
            width: 100,
            tooltip: 'Broadcast Frames: good frames with the broadcast destination address.',
            columns: [{
                header: 'TX',
                width: 50,
                align: 'center',
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'TX_BCAST',
                tooltip: 'Transmitted'
            }]
        }, {
            text: 'PAUSE',
            sortable: false,
            width: 100,
            tooltip: 'Pause Frames: pause frames internally generated by the MAC.',
            columns: [{
                header: 'TX',
                width: 50,
                align: 'center',
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'TX_PAUSE',
                tooltip: 'Transmitted'
            }]
        }]
    };
}
```

Later, I then getCount() via the grid's store and it comes back as empty.

```
console.log('grid store count', Ext.getCmp('eioaGrid').store.getCount());
```

Any ideas?  Been stumped for a couple of days now and I'm going mad!  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it... my reference to this.eioaGridStore when setting the grid store: was not in scope (was undefined)... everything now working.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess as I didn't load up your code, but maybe remove the autoload from the store definition since you are doing it manually?